# Pass by name in Scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming

What I'm trying to do is to have a new construct which can be called like this:

```
myFunc(10) {
   println("hello")
}
```

and prints 10 times `"hello"`.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use by-name parameters (this weird`=>` in second argument list) to do that:

```scala
def myFunc(count:Int)(todo: => Unit) = (0 until count).foreach(_ => todo)
//or
def myFunc(count:Int)(todo: => Unit) = for (c <- 0 until count) todo
```

more about that https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/by-name-parameters.html

https://scalafiddle.io/sf/hoQjz2L/0

Answer (score 1):

You can use a by-name parameter to achieve a built-in like construct:

```
 def runTimes(n: Int)(r: => Unit) = for(i <- 0 until n) r
```

You can use it the way you want:

```
runTimes(10) {
  println("hi")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do that by doing the following:

```
def myFunc(x: =>Int)(body: =>Unit):Unit = {
    if(x == 0) { () } else {
        body
        myFunc(x-1)(body)
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not using `!=` and avoid this empty code block?